# Is there standard parameters that characterize how fast neural network learns to achieve specific error rate?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I want to estimate how fast my model learn. Mb how many learn steps my model need to do to achieve specific error rate(precision/ recall/ MSE/ etc.). Any standard approach for measuring this?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can estimate that by smoothing out your *val_loss* curve and hoping that your training is repeatable and stable, but seems that word *"unpredictable"* was invented specifically to describe loss curves. :) Especially if you're using some sort of dynamic data generation or custom cost function.

Take a look at few species at http://lossfunctions.tumblr.com/